# Execute JavaScript code from a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript code created server side and passed to the client as a string by a rest request. I am trying to execute the code retrieved.
Any help would be appreciated.

Server side. The javascript code stored in a string.

```
(function() {

function createChart(selector) {
    $(selector).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
        },
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: true,
            type: "category"
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{

            data: datas    
        }],
    });
}

function render() {
    createChart('#chart');
}
return {
    render: render
}
}())
```

Client side (angular js)

```
    .controller('ChartController', ['$scope', 'charts',function ($scope, charts) {

        var test = charts.data;//contains the javascript code send by a rest request
        eval(test); 
        test.render(); 

}])
```

The execution of the script in the client side returns "test.render is not a function" in chrome

Any advices ?

Thank you very much

Comment: append a script tag to the page with the src being the serverside page

Comment: @epascarello . I think it's a good  way to do. so i need to store the string into a real javascript file server side then link it to the script tag client side right ? Thanks

Comment: No you just return the script, no need to create an actual file. That is how JSONP works.

Comment: @epascarello . I don t understand how it works because script tag point on a resource file . can you provide me some examples links please ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var result = eval(test); 
result.render();
```

Because your `test` is a string. The `result` of `eval(test)` is a function.

It is always not recommended to use `eval`. But if you really need it, [use angular `$eval` instead](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> If you want to eval() an Angular expression yourself, use the $eval() method.

Comment: Thanks it works but i guess it will be temporary until i find another solution because it's too dangerous but I needed it to work for my local tests. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute an arbitrary chunk of Javascript code but you should really, really avoid this when possible.

`eval` is a huge security problem since presumably you're getting that string from an outside source and who knows what they might try to run. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) for more information on why `eval` is evil.

Comment: Exactly right. using `eval()` opens the server up to malicious attack, as any externally supplied string has the power to (as an example) access the filesystem, gain control over your server processes etc.

Comment: @Mike C. Oh yeah you are right thank you, i made some researches about eval and it seems very dangerous... So what are the others safety option to eval a javascript string ? Thanks

Comment: @user902509 That's it. If you're going to evaluate a string, it's not safe. I'd suggest loading in your script another way.

Comment: @Mike C. But eval is only dangerous if we can access the code by a browser right ? Because in my case it's about a mobile application . Thanks

Comment: @user902509 It's dangerous no matter where you use it. Never trust user data. That's a golden rule of programming.

Comment: @Mike C . Thanks , i will use it for my local tests only until i find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the eval function like this :

```
var functionToEval = "functionName";
console.log(eval(functionToEval));
```

For more information on the eval function you can go see this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval